# jQuery .prepend calling twice on list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to add some markup in a set of list items. I basically want some icons added to before my anchor links within the LI.

```
<ul class="submenu-children">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>

$('.submemu-children li a').prepend('<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>');
```

Here is my JSFiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/4HfmS/

I semi got it working previously but it was actually outputting my HTML twice and sometimes four times, I just want it once for a single icon :)

I'm guessing I am targeting the selector wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: typo $('.submenu-children li a')

Comment: nothing is wrong here: http://jsfiddle.net/4HfmS/1/

Comment: Question, why don't you just style the list-items? It seems you just want to put an icon in place of your regular list-bullets. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Comment: If you change the `<i>` to `<span>X</span>` its easier to see it fail.

Comment: @RenéWolferink - I already did this but I wanted a rollerover with a sprite, but unfortunately if the LI proceed to 2 lines in my responsive design it broke and displayed twice. I think using a font inside an <i> tag is better for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submenu is spelled wrong.

Instead of this:

```
$('.submemu-children li a').prepend('<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>');
```

Use this:

```
$('.submenu-children li a').prepend('<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>');
```

Here's an example with the right libraries included (for the `icon-angle-right` class): [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKeefe/4HfmS/2/). It's only prepending once in this example.

Comment: How silly of me, thanks for pointing it out, was scratching my head for ages! :)